# How to build Gazebo packages with Indigo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.romin.upm.es/wiki/index.php?title=ROS%3ATutorials/Simulate_Your_Robot_in_Gazebo) to build a myrobot_gazebo package for Indigo with Gazebo 5.

I create my package with:

```
catkin_create_pkg myrobot_gazebo gazebo5_msgs gazebo5_plugins gazebo5_ros gazebo5_ros_control myrobot_description
```

then, when I try to update my dependencies with:

```
rosdep update
rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
myrobot_gazebo: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gazebo5_ros]
```

How do I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207904/how-to-build-gazebo-packages-with-indigo/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS packages names for the Gazebo 5 packages don't include the version number, even though the apt package names do.

For example, if you've installed `ros-indigo-gazebo5-ros`, your dependency should still be on `gazebo_ros`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-04-26**:
Thanks. I can't believe I missed this. I actually ran catkin_create_pkg with the non-version numbers first, and received a different error from rosdep, so I changed it to the versioned names. After I installed the gazebo5 packages with apt-get, I forgot to rerun the catkin_create_pkg.